# When exporting MXD to PDF, map layout moves to left?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, pdf, mxd

When I export an MXD to PDF, the layout has moved to the left. Exporting to JPEG doesn't cause this problem. If, for example, the map in layout view is of quad 2 and quad 3, the pdf will be of quad 1 and quad 2.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots? Are you using data driven pages?

Comment: I'm not using data driven pages, and unfortunately I can't provide screenshots. I know this isn't a lot of information to go on.

Comment: I would echo: check that DD pages is not turned on. This can happen accidentally or when reusing mxds.